# speed up slicing dicing of customers mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, elasticsearch

Currently we are using AWS RDS(Mysql) + Pandas. We have order, customers, products tables and so on. To get customers and do campaign based on various filters(total 18 filters) on those customers its taking too much time. "Order"'s table itself is of magnitude of million of rows. So to speed up We started doing poc with  elasticsearch as our filters contains too many text searches ex "product name", "vendor name",etc .

The problem we are facing with is
1) Filtering on AOV bucket ( average order value ) , with relavent document details also 
2) Filtering on Order count 
3) Filtering on first_order_date and last_order_date

Our document structure is

```
{
    "order_id":"6",
    "customer_id":"1",
    "customer_name":"shailendra",
    "mailing_addres":"shailendra@gmail.com",
    "actual_order_date":"2000-04-30",
    "is_veg":"0",
    "total_amount":"2499",
    "store_id":"276",
    "city_id":"12",
    "payment_mode":"cod",
    "is_elite":"0",
    "product":["1","2"],
    "coupon_id":"",
    "client_source":"1",
    "vendor_id":"",
    "vendor_name: "",
    "brand_id":"",
    "third_party_source":""

}
```

this is the query

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "customer_ids":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"customer_id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it return results as

```
{
  "took": 13,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "5",
          "customer_id": "5",
          "customer_name": "ashish",
          "mailing_addres": "ashish@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-05-30",
          "is_veg": "1",
          "total_amount": "300",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "8",
          "customer_id": "2",
          "customer_name": "nikhil",
          "mailing_addres": "nikhil@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-05-30",
          "is_veg": "0",
          "total_amount": "249",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "2",
          "customer_id": "2",
          "customer_name": "nikhil",
          "mailing_addres": "nikhil.01@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-01-30",
          "is_veg": "1",
          "total_amount": "255",
          "store_id": "1",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "4",
          "customer_id": "4",
          "customer_name": "vivek",
          "mailing_addres": "vivek@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-04-30",
          "is_veg": "0",
          "total_amount": "249",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "7",
          "customer_id": "1",
          "customer_name": "shailendra",
          "mailing_addres": "shailendra07121@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-05-30",
          "is_veg": "0",
          "total_amount": "249",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "1",
          "customer_id": "1",
          "customer_name": "shailendra",
          "mailing_addres": "shailendra07121@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-01-30",
          "is_veg": "1",
          "total_amount": "251",
          "store_id": "1",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "6",
          "customer_id": "4",
          "customer_name": "vivek",
          "mailing_addres": "vivek@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-05-30",
          "is_veg": "0",
          "total_amount": "249",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "customers4",
        "_type": "details",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": "3",
          "customer_id": "3",
          "customer_name": "manish",
          "mailing_addres": "manish@gmail.com",
          "actual_order_date": "2016-03-30",
          "is_veg": "0",
          "total_amount": "249",
          "store_id": "2",
          "city_id": "",
          "payment_mode": "cod",
          "is_elite": "0",
          "product": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "coupon_id": "",
          "client_source": "1",
          "vendor_id": "",
          "brand_id": "",
          "third_party_source": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "customer_ids": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "4",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "3",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "5",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

here as u can see only doc count is being returned. we want all fields of the document along with the doc count

Comment: Can you show what queries you've tried so far and how they fall short to achieve what you want?

Comment: this is the basic {
    "aggs": {
        "customer_ids":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"customer_id"
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to retrieve the documents for each customer bucket.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "customer_ids":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"customer_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "docs": {
                 "top_hits": {
                    "size": 3
                 }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. just wanted to know after applying group by can we filter the customers based on max(actual_order_date) of that customer between two dates?

Comment: You want only the most recent order date from that customer between two dates?

Comment: yes,last order date of customer between two dates and first order date of customer between two dates

Comment: Shall we do this in another question so as not to mix a different need with this one?

Comment: sure find the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976025/group-by-and-filter-maxdate-between-two-dates-in-elastic-search)