# Group by and filter max(date) between two dates in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Currently we are able to group by customer_id in elastic search.

Following is the document structure

```
{
    "order_id":"6",
    "customer_id":"1",
    "customer_name":"shailendra",
    "mailing_addres":"shailendra@gmail.com",
    "actual_order_date":"2000-04-30",
    "is_veg":"0",
    "total_amount":"2499",
    "store_id":"276",
    "city_id":"12",
    "payment_mode":"cod",
    "is_elite":"0",
    "product":["1","2"],
    "coupon_id":"",
    "client_source":"1",
    "vendor_id":"",
    "vendor_name: "",
    "brand_id":"",
    "third_party_source":""

}
```

Now we need to filter the group to find the documents

1. last  ordered date between two dates
2. first order date between two dates

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the query below. Within each customer bucket, we further filter all document between two dates (here I've taken the month of August 2016) and then we run a `stats` aggregation on the date field. The `min` value will be the first order date and the `max` value will be the last order date.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "customer_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "actual_order_date": {
                "gt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "lt": "2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_max": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "actual_order_date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this gives a min and max order date for each customer  ,but what i need is customers whose last order date between two given dates(input) and customers whose first order date between two dates(input) and these two input date range will be different.

Comment: Ok, I see, let me think about it